# Fraction NFT Marketplace (ERC20) - error in buyNFT - Not enough Ether sent to buy the shares

Tags: erc-20, tokens, nft, hardhat, erc-721

I'm trying to build fraction NFT Marketplace, It's now working when I try to create a new NFT and show it in the frontend.
I'm now facing an error in my buyNFT function and no matter what I try it keeps happening.

```
(reason="Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Not enough Ether sent to buy the shares.'", method="estimateGas",
```

can anyone guide me on what I should do?

this is my smart contract right now:

```
    pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "./CustomERC20.sol";

contract FractionalNFTMarketplace is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    using Strings for uint256;

    uint256 private _currentTokenId = 0;
    address public customERC20Address;

    struct FractionalToken {
        CustomERC20 token;
        uint256 totalShares;
        uint256 pricePerShare;
    }

    struct MarketItem {
        uint256 tokenId;
        address payable seller;
        address payable owner;
        uint256 totalShares;
        uint256 pricePerShare;
        bool isForSale;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => FractionalToken) private _fractionalTokens;
    mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => uint256)) private _shareOwners;
    mapping(uint256 => MarketItem) private _marketItems;

    Counters.Counter private _marketItemId;

    event TokenCreated(uint256 indexed tokenId, uint256 totalShares, uint256 pricePerShare);
    event TokenBought(uint256 indexed tokenId, address indexed buyer, uint256 shares);
    event MarketItemCreated(uint256 indexed tokenId, address indexed seller, uint256 totalShares, uint256 pricePerShare);
    event MarketItemSold(uint256 indexed marketItemId, address indexed buyer);
    event ApprovalForToken(uint256 indexed tokenId, address indexed owner, uint256 amount);

    constructor(address _customERC20Address) ERC721("Fractional NFT Marketplace", "FNFTM") {
        customERC20Address = _customERC20Address;
    }
    

    function createMarketItem(uint256 tokenId) private {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "Token ID does not exist.");

    address currentOwner = ownerOf(tokenId);

    FractionalToken storage fractionalToken = _fractionalTokens[tokenId];

    _marketItems[tokenId] = MarketItem(
        tokenId,
        payable(currentOwner),
        payable(address(this)),
        fractionalToken.totalShares,
        fractionalToken.pricePerShare,
        true
    );

    emit MarketItemCreated(tokenId, currentOwner, fractionalToken.totalShares, fractionalToken.pricePerShare);
}

    function createToken(uint256 totalShares, uint256 pricePerShare, string memory tokenURI) public payable returns (uint256) {
        require(totalShares > 0, "Total shares must be greater than 0.");
        require(pricePerShare > 0, "Price per share must be greater than 0.");
        
        uint256 newTokenId = _currentTokenId++;
        _mint(msg.sender, newTokenId);
        _setTokenURI(newTokenId, tokenURI);

        string memory name = string(abi.encodePacked("Shares of NFT #", newTokenId.toString()));
        string memory symbol = string(abi.encodePacked("SNFT", newTokenId.toString()));
        CustomERC20 newERC20Token = new CustomERC20(name, symbol);
        newERC20Token.mint(msg.sender, totalShares);

        _fractionalTokens[newTokenId] = FractionalToken(newERC20Token, totalShares, pricePerShare);
        _shareOwners[newTokenId][msg.sender] = totalShares;
        approveContractForToken(newTokenId,totalShares);
        createMarketItem(newTokenId);

        emit TokenCreated(newTokenId, totalShares, pricePerShare);
        return newTokenId;
    }

    function approveContractForToken(uint256 tokenId, uint256 amount) public {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "Token ID does not exist.");
        require(ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender, "Caller is not the owner of the token.");

        FractionalToken storage fractionalToken = _fractionalTokens[tokenId];
        fractionalToken.token.approve(address(this), amount);
        emit ApprovalForToken(tokenId, msg.sender, amount);
    }

    function getAllowance(uint256 tokenId, address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "Token ID does not exist.");
        FractionalToken storage fractionalToken = _fractionalTokens[tokenId];
        return fractionalToken.token.allowance(owner, spender);
    }

    function buyToken(uint256 tokenId,uint256 totalPrice, uint256 shares) public payable {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "Token ID does not exist.");
        require(shares > 0, "Shares must be greater than 0.");

        FractionalToken storage fractionalToken = _fractionalTokens[tokenId];
        require(fractionalToken.totalShares >= shares, "Not enough shares available.");

        // uint256 totalPrice = fractionalToken.pricePerShare * shares;
        require(msg.value >= totalPrice, "Not enough Ether sent to buy the shares.");

        address seller = ownerOf(tokenId);

        CustomERC20 customERC20 = CustomERC20(customERC20Address);
        uint256 allowance = customERC20.allowance(seller, address(this));

        require(allowance >= shares, "Not enough allowance to transfer shares.");

        customERC20.transferFrom(seller, msg.sender, shares);
        payable(seller).transfer(totalPrice);
        fractionalToken.totalShares -= shares;
        _shareOwners[tokenId][seller] -= shares;
        _shareOwners[tokenId][msg.sender] += shares;
        emit TokenBought(tokenId, msg.sender, shares);
    }
```

This is my context.js file that connects it with the front-end:

```
const CreateNft = async (name, price, shares, image, description, router) => {
        if (!name || !description || !price || !image || !shares)
          return console.log("Data is Missing!");
      
        const data = JSON.stringify({ name, description, image });
        try {
          const added = await client.add(data);
          const url = `https://infura-ipfs.io/ipfs/${added.path}`;

          await createSale(url, price, shares);

        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
    };

    //Create Sale
    const createSale = async (url, Price, shares, isResale, id) => {
      try {
        const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(Price, "ether");
        const contract = await SmartContractConnect();
    
        const transaction = !isResale
          ? await contract.createToken(shares, price, url)
          : await contract.resellToken(id, price);
    
        await transaction.wait();
        console.log("Transaction Completed: ", transaction);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error while creating sale: ", error);
      }
  };

    //Fetch NFTS
    const FetchNFTs = async () => {
        try {
          const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider();
          const contract = fetchSmartContract(provider);
      
          const data = await contract.fetchMarketItems();
          // console.log("Data: ", data);
          const items = await Promise.all(
            data.map(async ({ tokenId, seller,owner, pricePerShare,totalShares  }) => {
              const TokenURI = await contract.tokenURI(tokenId);
              const {
                data: { image, name, description },
              } = await axios.get(TokenURI);
      
              const price = ethers.utils.formatUnits(pricePerShare.toString(), "ether");

              return {
                price,
                tokenId: tokenId.toNumber(),
                seller,
                owner,
                image,
                name,
                description,
                TokenURI,
                totalShares: totalShares.toNumber()
              };
            })
          );
          // console.log("Fetch success: ", items);
          return items;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Error while fetching NFTs:  ", error);
        }
      };

    useEffect(()=>{
        FetchNFTs();
    },[]);

//Buy NFTs
    const BuyNFT = async (NFT, shares) => {
        try {
          const contract = await SmartContractConnect();
          const price = NFT.price*(shares)
          const totalPrice = ethers.utils.parseUnits(price.toString(), "ether");

      
          const transaction = await contract.buyToken(NFT.tokenId,totalPrice, shares);
      
          await transaction.wait();
          router.push("/profile");
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Error while buying NFT", error);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with this line:

```
      const transaction = await contract.buyToken(NFT.tokenId,totalPrice, shares);
```

You are not correctly specifying the value, which is the amount of Ether you want to send with the transaction. In this case the amount to `buyToken`

To fix the issue, you need to include the `value` when calling the `buyToken` function.

Like this:

```
const transaction = await contract.buyToken(NFT.tokenId, totalPrice, shares, {
    value: totalPrice, // Add this line
});
```

Comment: I noticed this a while ago but I'm now facing another issue: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'ERC20: insufficient allowance'

I have updated my code in the question above for the most recent one, can you help me figuring it out?

Comment: Please create a new question I would be happy to answer it :)

Comment: posted it in a new question, thanks for replying!

Comment: Hey adam, would appreciate any help in the other question as i'm facing hard time solving it, thank you